# Isogenous abelian schemes over a smooth variety over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth variety over a finite field. Let $X$ and $Y$ be isogenous abelian schemes over $S$.

Must $X$ and $Y$ be either isomorphic or constant as abelian schemes over $S$?

Comment: No. Any non-constant elliptic curve $X/S$ will have $End(E) = \mathbb{Z}$ so if $G$ is a finite cyclic subgroup of $X$, then $Y=X/G$ cannot be isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $X$ (or $Y$) is ordinary over the generic point of $S$ then $X$ is constant over $S$ iff $Y$ is constant over $S$.